# A problem with `Eliminate`.`

Tags: polynomials, algebraic-manipulation

Consider this expression:

```
Eliminate[a  x + b  y == 0 && c  x + d  y == 0, {x, y}]
```

`Mathematica` returns `True`, which is correct, but I would like to assume that $(x, y) \neq (0, 0),$ and get the determinant condition. Is there some way to do this?

Comment: Igor, If you mean to have `ad-bc==0` as the determinant condition, would you accept/be able to work with ad==bc or any variation there-of?

Comment: @CATrevillian yes, that would be fine, and, in fact, adding another equation $x+y==1$ does return this condition, but it is a bit kludgy ;)

Answer (score 7):

I assume that by determinant condition you mean

$$b c - a d=0$$

Right?

```
eqns = a*x + b*y == 0 && c*x + d*y == 0; 
Resolve[Exists[{x}, eqns]]
```

produces the above result

Comment: It's buried in a sea of logical statements, though, but it does give a good hint to a path to take.

Answer (score 3):

Because x and y are two unknowns, but there are only two equations. You can only eliminate one unknowns:

```
Eliminate[a*x + b*y == 1 && c*x + d*y == 2, {x}]
```

Answer (score 3):

Trying

```
Eliminate[ a x + b y == 0 && c x + d y == 0 && (x != 0 || y != 0), {x, y}]
```

gives

```
(a==(b c)/d&&d!=0)||(b==(a d)/c&&c!=0)||(c==0&&d==0)
```

Which is not quite what one would want, but...

Answer (score 1):

```
Resolve[Exists[{x, y}, 
a x + b y == 0 && c x + d y == 0 && {x, y} != 0 && a d != 0 && b c != 0]]
```

Gives

```
a != 0 && b != 0 && c != 0 && d != 0 && b c - a d == 0
```

Whereas

```
Resolve[Exists[{x, y}, 
a x + b y == 0 && c x + d y == 0 && x != 0 && y != 0
&& a != 0 && b != 0 && c != 0 && d != 0]]
```

Gives

```
b c - a d == 0 && a != 0 && b != 0 && c != 0 && d != 0
```

But I can't seem to have it give

```
a d - b c == 0
```

Hope this helps, Igor!

You might be able to brute-force it with some assumptions, but I can't seem to find the right combination at the moment.